# No Recipient Specified in RingCentral Fax API

Tags: php, fax, ringcentral

Can anyone help me out to get the solution for error code 3 in RingCentral Fax API integration Responses i.e., "No Recipient Specified"? I am getting all time the same response when I am passing the Recipient Fax Number.

Solution will be highly appreciated, please.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. In my case, the error occurred because I gave an invalid number for the Recipient. Try verifying the number you are sending is valid.